# Oracle 11g: nclob datatype cloumn showing question marks instead of multilingual characters

Tags: java, database, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g database with my application.
One of the DB table having one column with NCLOB datatype.
When I tried to insert Greek words or other language(German, Chinese, etc) words through application then the column contains only question marks instead of letters.

Following are the existing database NLS properties and its values:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16
```

What changes needs to do for the existing database which already contains the huge records of existing customers?

Any help related to this topic will support me a lot.
Thanks in advance.